# On the hunt for him VS On his hunt

Tags: idioms, word-usage

I know the idiom *On the hunt*
But I have a question about the usage.

I believe these are correct:
**He was on the hunt for clues.**
**She was on the hunt for the escaped criminal.**

However, (1) can I use it like this?
And (2), have I compromised the meaning?
**He was on her hunt.**
**They were on his hunt.**

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to be more economical.

Thank you very much!

Comment: No, you can't say that, but you can say "on her trail", which is a similar meaning (originally from hunting).

Comment: To me, "on his hunt" implies "hunting on his behalf", or that whomever "his" refers to has organised a hunting party.

Answer (score 1):

No, *on his hunt* would not readily be understood by most English speakers.

It is risky to try and explain why particular expressions are not idiomatic, but in this case the fact that *hunt* takes "for" rather than "of" in this sense.

In fact, there are two related but different senses of *hunt*, which take different arguments:

Transitive *hunt* means "pursue a person or animal, to capture or kill them/it", as in *hunt the stag/bear/fugitive*. When it is used as a noun, it can be specified by a noun modifier, but not normally by a possessive or prepositional phrase: *a bear hunt*, but not **the bear's hunt* or **a hunt of the bear*. *A hunt for a bear* is possible, but shades over into the other meaning (below). To get a nominal phrase with a definite object we would usually say *hunting the bear*.

The other meaning of *hunt* is *search for*, and that takes an indirect object with *for* (not *of*). So *hunt for my glasses* means "search, trying to find my glasses". *Hunt for the bear* would normally mean "try to find the bear", while *hunt the bear* means "chase or stalk the bear, to capture or kill it".

This sense can be nominalised as *the hunt for the bear* but not **hunt of the bear* or **the bears' hunt*.